# How to verify if an element from an array isn't present in another array in as3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

So i have a lot of pictures that are displayed.For every picture you need to imput the correct word(answer) displayed in the picture. After you imput the word it is pushed in an array aUserAnswers. All the correct answers are in the aCorrectAnswers array. When a wrong answer is entered a wrong image is displayed and the user can enter another answer. When a correct answer is entered the game goes to the next level and the image is changed.
This is what i've managed to do but it doesn't work properly. I need it to verify ig the entered string is pressend in the specified array. Also i don't want to make it possible for exemple if in the first image is a dog and the array contains (dog, cat, cow) to be able to move futher by entering cow because is present in the array.

How to change this code to work in my condition?

Please tell me if you need extra details i'm new to flash and maybe i didn't explained myself right. THX

```
var aCorrectAnswers:Array = new Array("chicken", "ladybug", "cow", "dog");
var aUserAnswers:Array = new Array();
 wrong.visible = false;

submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, quiz);

var poza:int = 2;

function quiz(e:MouseEvent):void {
     aUserAnswers.splice(0);
     aUserAnswers.push(answers_txt.text);
     trace (aUserAnswers);

 // var len:int = aCorrectAnswers.length;
for(var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    trace("sunt aici");
    var j:Number=0;
    if (aCorrectAnswers[j].toString() == aUserAnswers.toString())
    {

        trace("aici");
       j++;
       pictures.gotoAndStop(j+1);
    }
    else
    {
         wrong.visible = true;
        wrong.gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your data structure for a quiz type thing is working against you in this case. I would instead setup an object array. This way you can keep track of the current question and not have to worry about them answering "cow" when they are on "dog". Review this below:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.*;

var currentQuestion:Number = 0;
var quiz:Array = new Array(
    {
        "question": "What is this?",
        "answer": "chicken",
        "image": "chicken.png"
    },
    {
        "question": "What is this?",
        "answer": "dog",
        "image": "dog.png"
    },
    {
        "question": "What is this?",
        "answer": "cat",
        "image": "cat.png"
    },
    {
        "question": "What is this?",
        "answer": "cow",
        "image": "cow.png"
    }
);

function submitAnswer(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //-- if something is in the text field check the answer
    if (answerText.text.length > 0)
    {
        var userAnswer = answerText.text;
        if (userAnswer == quiz[currentQuestion].answer) //-- if user answer is the same as the "answer" prop in the quiz obj array
        {
            submitBtn.enabled = false;
            wrongText.text = "Correct!";
            //-- set a little delay before the next question
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                submitBtn.enabled = true;
                wrongText.text = "";
                answerText.text = "";
                currentQuestion++;
                loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
            },1500);

        }
        else
        {
            wrongText.text = "Please try again.";
        }
    }
}
submitBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, submitAnswer);

function loadQuestion(id):void
{
    questionText.text = quiz[id].question;
    //-- if an image is in imageholder, remove it
    if (imageHolder.numChildren) imageHolder.removeChildAt(0);
    var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
    ldr.load(new URLRequest(quiz[id].image));
    imageHolder.addChild(ldr);
}
//-- loadQuestion accepts an id which will be used for referencing the quiz array.
//-- loadQuestion(0) will load the first question, chicken, loadQuestion(1) will load the second question, dog, etc.
loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
```

view the demo: http://ronnieswietek.com/_random/quizdemo/quiz.swf

**edit 1:** I didn't code this to check for last question or anything. This is just for conceptual purposes.

**edit 2 showing how to convert text input to uppercase:**

```
function textChange(e:Event):void
{
    answerText.text = answerText.text.toUpperCase();
}
answerText.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, textChange);
```

Comment: thx a lot this is very helpfull if i manage to change the way the picture is added is perfect because i need it to get my picture when a random number is called so every picture is called randomly. as i've noticed here the pictures are called from the library.

Comment: @AlexandruBalea, not exactly, they are loaded externally hence the need for the `Loader` class.

Comment: it is `yourString.toUpperCase();`

Comment: well i want when the user inserts the text the letters to appear in UpperCase. where to apply this function for this exemple?

Comment: updated my comment, but really that question wasn't asked in your original question that I was aware of.

Answer (score 0):

To check if an item is in an array you can simply use `array.indexOf(item)`. It returns the position of the item (the index) if the item is in the array, or `-1` if it isn't in the array.

```
if(myArray.indexOf("something") >= 0){
    trace("yes, it's in the array!");
} else {
    trace("no, it's not in the array...");
}
```

Comment: So you didn't need to verify if an element was inside of an array?